# потоковая передача экрана в интернет без пауз

Tags: видео, streaming

У меня вопрос: возможна ли потоковая передача картинки с экрана на веб-сайт без задержек? Например, так же, как в Скайпе: там вы можете показать экран вашему собеседнику безо всяких задержек.

Я пробовал добиться этого через twitch.tv, VLC, но у меня получалась задержка порядка 15 секунд.

Может, есть какие-нибудь другие решения этой проблемы?

Comment: Please use http://stackoverflow.com or other English-speaking communities for questions in English. Thanks.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что вопрос на английском языке.

Comment: раз уж есть ответ, перевёл и вопрос

Answer (score 1):

[Статья](http://www.waitwut.info/blog/2013/06/09/desktop-streaming-with-ffmpeg-for-lower-latency/) старенькая, но аккурат по теме. В общем, связкой ffserver + ffmpeg возможно добиться искомого результата.

Comment: А если у меня windows ? ))

Comment: ffmpeg - кроссплатформенный проект, также как и vlc.

Comment: Ну ffmpeg да, а ffserver ? Его же только под linuxom можно запустить..

Comment: М-да, точно, нельзя. Ну тогда если только поступить как Магомет и отправиться к горе.